# Show that the center of the circumscribed circle of the triangle ABC is on the line AE.

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let $ABC$ a triangle with $AB <AC$. The angle bisector of $\angle BAC$ intersects $(BC)$ in $D$. The perpendicular from $B$  on $AD$ intersects the circumscribed circle of the triangle $ABD$ in $E$ for the second time.

Show that the center of the circumscribed circle $S$ of the triangle $ABC$ is on the line $AE$.

Comment: To clarify, the height from B of triangle ABD intersects AD at E?

Comment: No, the height intersects the circumscribed circle of the triangle ABD in E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AD$ and $AE$ cuts $S$ at $F$ and $H$. Let $\angle BAF = \angle FAC = \alpha$ and $\angle CBA = \beta$, $\angle BCA = \gamma$.

Then $F$ halves arc $BC$ (which doesn't contains $A$) and we have $$ \angle FBC =\angle FCB = \alpha$$

Then $$\angle FHA = \angle FCA = \gamma+\alpha$$

Also we have $$\angle HAF \equiv \angle EAF = \angle EBD = \beta +\alpha-90^{\circ}$$

So $$\angle AFH = 180^{\circ}-(\beta +\alpha-90^{\circ}) -(\gamma+\alpha) =90^{\circ}$$
and thus center of $S$ must lie on $AH $.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

let $O$ be the center Let $H$ be the point were the bisector intersects the circumscribed circle of $ABC$. WE can easily prove that $(OH)$ is the perpendicular bisector of $[BC]$.
You need to prove $\angle AED=180^\circ$ 
I'll let you finish with a lot of subtended angles

Comment: The perpendicular from B on AD intersects the circumscribed circle of ABD in E.

Comment: @Problemsolving what's wrong with the figure?, i dont understand